# How to add point labels to my plot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Below I am trying to plot a stick knot in 3 dimensions. I would like to label each of the points in order p1, p2, p3... p6 or even just 1, 2, 3, ... 6 would suffice. How do I do that?

`

```
P1 = {0.300775, 1.301248, -0.702434}
P2 = {-0.976281, -0.910795 , 0.701983}
P3 = {0.976171, -0.910795, -0.702076}
P4 = {-0.300495 , 1.300967, 0.702620}
P5 = {-1.276451, -0.390204, -0.702474}
P6 =  {1.276282, -0.390420 , 0.702381}
Knot = {P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P1}
Show[
 Graphics3D[Line[Knot]],
 Graphics3D[Point[Knot]],
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

`

Here is the picture of the output:

[image: Trefoil Knot with sticks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Show[Graphics3D[Line[Knot]], 
 Graphics3D[
  MapIndexed[Text[Style["P" <> ToString[#2[[1]]], Medium, Red], #,{-1,-1}] &, 
   Knot[[;;-2]]]], Graphics3D[Point[Knot]], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately its tough to get text in 3d to actually look good.

Here`s that map without the style to make it a bit easier to understand.

```
MapIndexed[Text["P" <> ToString[ #2[[1]] ], #] &
```

Comment: That looks good enough for my uses. Thank you, can you just explain to me what # and & do?

Comment: that is *pure function* syntax: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html.